# How can I prove source of my savings which I accumulated from my old job. UK visitor visa

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

i am applying for a UK visitor visa but has a problem with funds

I have enough savings for the trip but this money came from my previous job. I have been a housewife for 3 years now. I still have the savings in my bank and dont have to use it because my husband pays for everything.
Do I need to get bank statements from 3-4 years ago detailing payroll transactions to prove that my money is legit?

Comment: Probably. Your employment contract and payslips would be useful as well. Depends how much you’re talking about, if it’s £000’s you’re more likely to need to show provenance, if it’s just a few £00 or so likely doesn’t matter that much given the timeframe

Comment: @Traveller : it is not a small sum, well at least for me haha. £000 im talking about. I dont have the contract or payslips with me anymore :( my husband is sponsoring me for the trip though. We were talking about withholding this information about my savings because its difficult to show provenance.

Comment: I may be wrong and I’m too lazy to check at this time, but I don’t believe there is a requirement to prove the origin of funds for savings. As long as you can show it’s been there for 6 months and you have a credible story about how you saved that money (I.e. you’re not a retired person who worked a minimum wage job all their life but somehow has a million quid on their savings account with no explanation), they can’t ask much about it. Provenance of funds is more for recent money coming into your account. Hopefully somehow can confirm this with sources…

Comment: Are you using these savings to pay for the trip, or is your husband paying for the trip?

Comment: Why would you not want to tell them the truth (which you have just told us)? What possible harm could it do?

Comment: @DJClayworth my husband is paying for everything. My savings are in a fixed term where i get around 5.6% of interest on the maturity date so i dont want to withdraw it since my husband can and will afford the trip if that makes sense

Comment: @mdewey to be honest it just means more hassle and legwork getting 3-4 years worth of bank statements from like 5 of my accounts (we kinda diversify our finance sources).  But we deceided to go extra miles anyway :)

Answer (score 4):

If you have had the money in your account for the six months covered by the requested bank statements then immigration will not care much where it came from. It's clearly yours, and that's what they care about. Plus if your husband is paying for your trip, and his financial situation is good enough to be able to afford that, then the presence of that money won't make the difference between acceptance and rejection.

The reason for explaining fund origins is to prevent the suspicion that you have arranged a short term boost to your account to make it look like you have enough money when you don't. Since you clearly haven't done that there won't be a problem.

Of course explaining the money origin won't hurt. Write it in the notes or cover letter if you are in any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, with the usual bank statement, attaching a letter that says what you described above will be more than ok for the officer. If you can provide the statements in which you can show funds arriving, it would be good as a supplementary evidence. Note that your situation is not uncommon and officers should have already seen such cases.

Please don't withhold the information about the bank account. It can only harm your application.

Comment: Are you basing this on personal experience? Third party reports? Official  instructions? Some sources references would be useful

Comment: Haha i can bombard the officer with everything just wondering if i have enough funds for the trip (through my husband's sponsorship) then why i need to show them extra money that im not gonna use for the trip

Comment: @Trangtran I had a similar situation. My wife has a bank account. But no regular job. So, not much funds there other than occasional transfer from me. Still we included that statement.

Comment: @Trangtran Just last 6 month statement as mentioned and a covering letter explaining your circumstance can be in your favor.